# Use 4 points, 2 of which are local min and max, to create polynomial equation

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I was trying to generate a plot to illustrate something to a friend over text message, and then spent two hours going down the rabbit hole before eventually giving up, so now I'm asking out of curiosity.

I have 4 points that I want to turn into a polynomial equation.

$$
(0, 0)\\
(1, 0.6)\\
(2.5, 0.25)\\
(7, 0.9)
$$

`(1, 0.6)` is a local maximum and `(2.5, 0.25)` is a local minimum.  The end behaviors of the graph are negative as x goes to -infinity and positive as x goes to infinity.

My first thought was to put the points in a matrix and compute reduced row echelon form in order to get the coefficients.  This didn't take into account my local min/max restrictions.

Then I thought to start with $f'(x) = (x - 1)(x - 2.5)$ and integrate, but of course that doesn't get me the right magnitude nor hit $(7, 0.9)$.  It was at this point that I realized this is probably more than a 3rd order polynomial, and that I was out of my depth.

Is there a process that someone who hasn't done calculus in the last 13-14 years could learn?

Comment: Have you looked at  Lagrange polynomials?

Comment: I vaguely recognize the name, but don't know what they are.

Comment: They allow you to construct a polynomial that goes through any points (assuming none are in the same vertical line). However, I'm not sure how you could enforce certain points to be local max/min.

Comment: Why doesn't integration work? Multiply a constant times your expression for $f'(x)$. That will give you the freedom to account for the magnitude at $x=7$.

Comment: @JohnDouma actually, that route only gave me one point: (0,0).  I could multiply by a coefficient to get one more point of my choosing, but not the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have six conditions: the value of the function at four points and the value of the derivative at two. So try a polynomial of degree $5$ with six unknown coefficients. The conditions will give you six linear equations in those six unknowns. Solve those equations.

There is a small chance that the points where the derivative is $0$ won't be the local maximum and minimum you want. Then try a polynomial of higher degree and play with the freedom that buys you.

Comment: That seems reasonable, though I don't have any idea how to calculate the coefficients when there are degrees of freedom.  If it's not too complex, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: @dx_over_dt For a fifth degree polynomial there won't be any degrees of freedom. Row echelon form will tell you the unique answer if there is one. With a higher order polynomial, row echelon form will tell you a set of parameters you can set arbitrarily. (This is standard linear algebra U don't have time to do. Maybe someone will edit my answer or provide another with those calculations.)